# how to rotate view with navigation controll?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uiscrollview, uiimageview

```
@implementation MainViewController

@synthesize scrollView,imageView;

    - (id) init { 


    if (self != nil) {
        self.title = @"Evolution";
    }
    return self;}
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;


    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

    int numberOfImages = 32;
    CGFloat currentX = 0.0f;

    for (int i=1; i <= numberOfImages; i++) {

        // create image
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"page-%d.jpg", i];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

        // put image on correct position
        CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
        rect.origin.x = currentX;
        imageView.frame = rect;

        // update currentX
        currentX +=454; //mageView.frame.size.width;

        [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
        [imageView release];
    }
    [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(currentX, 800);
    scrollView.pagingEnabled=YES;
    scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 15;
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;
    scrollView.bounces = NO;
    scrollView.bouncesZoom = NO;
    scrollView.delegate = self;

    scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    [scrollView release];
    [super viewDidLoad];}
     - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    return YES;}

    -(void)tapDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{

        ImageViewController *settings = [[ImageViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:settings animated:YES];

    [settings release];}

@end

@implementation ImgScrollViewAppDelegate

    @synthesize window;@synthesize viewController;
    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application{
    LogMethod();
    // If you want the status bar to be hidden at launch use this:
    // application.statusBarHidden = YES;
    //
    // To set the status bar as black, use the following:
    // application.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque;


    // Create window
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // this helps in debugging, so that you know "exactly" where your views are placed;
    // if you see "red", you are looking at the bare window, otherwise use black
    // window.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    viewController = [ [ MainViewController alloc ] init ];

    navigationController = [ [ UINavigationController alloc ] initWithRootViewController: viewController ];

    /* Anchor the view to the window */
    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];

    /* Make the window key and visible */
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
} 
@end
```

in above code i have problem that is when check it on simulator then rotate device left and right. But view not change and i want to change it. how i modify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view controller implementation there is a method `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation`. If you want it to rotate to any orientation, make it return `YES`. If you only want it to autorotate to some orientations, add an if statement to check and return yes or no.